# How to style file upload input using font awesome icon and then show the file name with a specific style?

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```
<div class="clip-upload">
 <label for="file-input">
  <i class="fa fa-paperclip fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
 </label>
 <input type="file" name="file-input" id="file-input">
</div>
```

with the CSS:

```
.clip-upload > input
{
    display: none;
}
```

so that it's just the paper clip icon that shows up as the button to upload a file.

I have 2 questions:

1. How can I make the name of the file uploaded appear as it does with a regular upload input? Note: I don't want it to replace the paper clip icon, I want the file names to be positioned on the page, with CSS (like in a new row, see below image).
2. How can I style this file name so that it has a background color, and border radius, like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have to use a lil jQuery (can be done in vanilla JS too) to use another element to contain the file name

- hide your input
- use the paperclip as your button
- on change you
  can grab the value of the input file name and add it to the newly
  created element.

***Note: the appended names will not actually submit this way I will leave that to you.***

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.file-input').change(function() {
    $file = $(this).val();
    $file = $file.replace(/.*[\/\\]/, ''); //grab only the file name not the path
    $('.filename-container').append("<span  class='filename'>" + $file + "</span>").show();
  })

})
```

```css
.rounded {
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 4px;
}

.in1 {
  width: 120px;
}

.in2 {
  width: 350px;
}

i {
  margin: 0 8px;
}

.filename-container {
  margin: 20px 20px 0 0;
}

.filename {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 15px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: 'verdana', sans-serif;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="clip-upload">
  <input class="rounded in1" value="other input" /> <input class="rounded in2" value="other input larger" />
  <label for="file-input">
  <i class="fa fa-paperclip fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
 </label> <i class="fa fa-play fa-lg"></i>
  <input type="file" class="file-input hide" name="file-input" id="file-input">
  <div class="filename-container hide"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much.